# splitting a string column in spark sql based on scenario

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

**A particular Column pattern is like this**

```
10-Apple
11-Mango
Orange
78-Pineapple
45-Grape
```

**And I want to make two columns out of it**

```
col1  col2
10    Apple
11    Mango
null  Orange
78    Pineapple
45    Grape
```

When I split the below string

```
SELECT split("10-Apple",'-',2)
```

It gives me `["10","Apple"]` which is correct

But when I split below string which has no delimiter(-)

```
SELECT split("Orange",'-',2)
```

It gives me `["Orange"]`

How can I have **null** instead of second element in the first place.

Like this `[null,"Orange"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `regexp_extract`

```
df.withColumn("number", regexp_extract($"column", "(\\d+)?\\-?(.*)", 1))
  .withColumn("fruit", regexp_extract($"column", "(\\d+)?\\-?(.*)", 2))
```

Regex means

- `(\\d+)?` First capturing group, any number may be present or not
- `\\-?` Literal dash, again may be present or not
- `(.*)` any number of characters after the previous characters

OUTPUT

```
+------------+------+---------+
|      column|number|    fruit|
+------------+------+---------+
|    10-Apple|    10|    Apple|
|    11-Mango|    11|    Mango|
|      Orange|      |   Orange|
|78-Pineapple|    78|Pineapple|
|    45-Grape|    45|    Grape|
+------------+------+---------+
```

**EDIT**

Using Spark SQL from your comment

```
scala> spark.sql("""select distinct column, regexp_extract(column, "(\\d+)?\\-?(.*)", 1) as number, regexp_extract(column, "(\\d+)?\\-?(.*)", 2) as fruit from table""").show
+------------+------+---------+
|      column|number|    fruit|
+------------+------+---------+
|    10-Apple|    10|    Apple|
|    11-Mango|    11|    Mango|
|    45-Grape|    45|    Grape|
|      Orange|      |   Orange|
|78-Pineapple|    78|Pineapple|
+------------+------+---------+
```

Comment: .withColumn("fruit", regexp_extract($"column", "(\\d+)?\\-?(.*)", 2)) gives me -Apple,-Mango,-Orange... how to fix that?

Comment: really? It's working fine for me using spark 3

df.withColumn("number", regexp_extract($"column", "(\\d+)?\\-?(.*)", 1)).withColumn("fruit", regexp_extract($"column", "(\\d+)?\\-?(.*)", 2))

Comment: Im doing this ,  select 
distinct column,
regexp_extract(column, "(\\d+)?\\-?(.*)", 1) as number,
regexp_extract(column, "(\\d+)?\\-?(.*)", 2) as fruit from table ........ and it gives me fruits including delimiter(-)

Comment: i updated the answer with your code, using spark sql... I don't know why the different behaviour.

Comment: It was because I had white spaces in between Ex. (10 - Apple) .. regexp_extract(column, "(\\d+)?\\\s?-?(.*)", 2) this fixed the issue.